# How to display only negative numbers in brackets on Crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, format, report

In Crystal report I have Amount column in detail section on crystal report Like:

```
  Amount  
 -90083.89 
 -87653.70 
  10008.00
```

Expected Result in Amount Column:
Amount
(90083.89)
(87653.70)
10008.00

[crystal report image as a reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMqeD.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the format to brackets for negatives in the field formatting options, under Format Field, then Number > Customise > Negatives

[image: screenshot]

If you're formatting via code then you'll need to use an `if` statement.